# How to acces sdcard and return and array with files off a specific format?

Tags: android

I need to acces the sdcard and return some files of different formats. The location will be input by the user. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simondid,
I believe this is what you are looking for.

**Accessing the SDCard:**
[reading a specific file from sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779944/reading-a-specific-file-from-sdcard-in-android)

**Keep in mind checking the media availability:**
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

**Creating a file filter:**
http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-implement-java-filefilter-list-files-directory

**Example of a mp3 file filter, Create the following filter class:**

```
import java.io.*;

/**
 * A class that implements the Java FileFilter interface.
 * It will filter and grab only mp3
 */
public class Mp3FileFilter implements FileFilter
{
  private final String[] okFileExtensions = 
    new String[] {"mp3"};

  public boolean accept(File file)
  {
    for (String extension : okFileExtensions)
    {
      if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Then based on the earlier post of accessing the sdcard you would use the filter like this:**

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdcard, "path/to/the/directory/with/mp3");

//THIS IS YOUR LIST OF MP3's
File[] mp3List = dir.listFiles(new Mp3FileFilter());
```

**NOTE: The code is rough you probably want to make sure the sdcard is available as mentioned above**

Comment: ty for the awsome answere but im having a hard time getting the filter to work i need it to test to media / music files just mp3 for now pleas help

Comment: i need the filter to return all mp3 files from a given folder

Comment: simon, you can check for the filetype by using `String.contains(".mp3");` on the filepath of the given directory/file.

Comment: pheonixblade ty for the tip but i solved it this why

FileFilter filterDirectoriesOnly = new FileFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File file) {
         return file.getName().endsWith("mp3");
      }
  };
 
   Log.i("state", "filter don");
  File[] sdDirectories = yourFile.listFiles(filterDirectoriesOnly);